# byte array of default encoding to byte array of ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, arrays

i have a byte array having default encoding.
i want to change that byte array to byte array of `"ISO-8859-1"` encoding.
How to do this..?
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] isoBytes = new String(curBytes).getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

note however, that if the default encoding has already "lost" some characters, you cannot recover them this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = new String(currentByteArray);
byte[] newByteArray = str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a String transformed to a byte array using the default platform encoding (whatever it is. And you want to transform this string to a byte array using ISO-8859-1.

The first step is thus to transform the byte array to a String:

```
String s = new String(bytes); // default encoding used here
```

and then to transform it back to a byte array:

```
byte[] iso88591Bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```